# KALLYAS theme Circular Content Style slider not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, jcarousel, sliders

I set up [KALLYAS theme](http://themeforest.net/item/kallyas-responsive-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/4091658) on my client's WoprdPress site. Everything went well but, the slider doesn't move.

Check this out...

http://www.businessdiligence.co/?page_id=1407

There's no and arrows on  the edges of the slider but I can see in the theme's demo page.

Can you please help me with this...

Thanks